# Find an email address in a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, email

I wondered if anyone has any idea how to best do this in php.

I have a string in a variable and I want to pull an email address from it (if one exists).

The string could be along the lines of :

"My email address is myemail@mydomain.com and I would appreciate it if you contact me"

I know I can validate if an email is valid or not but wondered how to search a string and extract the email.

IE:  I can use filters to validate the email but I am stuck at how to search the string to see if it has an email.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: A short hint to get you going: read about regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for that @AbraCadaver - Much appreciated.

Comment: @arkascha - No, i'm not scraping email addresses from the web.  If I wanted to do that I would use one of the many scraper libs around.  The string is coming from a user filled in textarea.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what that preg_match needs tweaking @AbraCadaver but not getting far.  It is grabbing the email address but not the tld from the end.  So myemail@mydomain.com matches as myemail@mydomain

Comment: Just found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865113/extract-email-address-from-string-php

That seems to do the trick.

Thank you everyone for your help - I feel a little foolish that I didn't find the answer from search on SO  !

Comment: Posted a better one that will capture what you want, but then still needs to be validated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get email address from a long string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028553/how-to-get-email-address-from-a-long-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fairly well.  You'll get things that appear to be an email address though they may not be valid.  Then use `filter_var()` to check if it's valid.

```
preg_match('/\b[^\s]+@[^\s]+/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Match:

- A *word boundary* `\b` followed by
- NOT *white space* `[^\s]+` followed by
- A `@` followed by
- NOT *white space* `[^\s]+`

Comment: This worked for me too but my string contains an email with a colon at the end and this regex does not remove the colon. Any help?

Comment: @CesarBielich Probably just change last `[^\s]+` to something like `[\w\d.-]+`

Comment: @CesarBielich: Or as a hack if they all have a colon just add to the negative char class `[^\s:]`

Comment: @Abr `[^\s]` = `\S`.  `[^\s:]` will not allow any colons in the email address (which may actually be valid).